# how do you call a function inside a foreach statement

Tags: php, arrays, function, foreach

I am trying to use foreach statment to run through a function that preg_replaces using regular expression. Can someone help, because my method doesn't work..

```
$reg_sent is an array

function reg_sent($i){
  $reg_sent = "/[^A-Za-z0-9.,\n\r ]/";
  return preg_replace($reg_sent, '', $i);
}

foreach($reg_sent as $key=>$value){
  $value = reg_sent($value);
}
```

Comment: Having a function with the same name as a variable might be confusing the PHP interpreter. Try naming it something different.

Comment: What does the function actually do when you run it? What results do you get?

Comment: It updates $value, but $value is a __copy__ of the array element unless the foreach is modified to a reference &$value (which has its own problems for novices, not least that you need to unset($value) after ending the foreach loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php).

```
$reg_sent = array_map("reg_sent", $reg_sent);
```

This will call `reg_sent` on every cell of the array, and return a new array with values modified. You can replace the `foreach` block you stated, with the above.

Answer (score 0):

You're not getting any affect because the `foreach` loop needs to access the elements by reference:

```
foreach($reg_sent as $key => &$value)
{
    $value = reg_sent($value);
}
```

Note that I added the `&` in the loop before `$value`. Otherwise, `foreach` operates on **a copy** of the value, and when that is modified within the loop, you will never see that value outside of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your variable by reference:

```
foreach($reg_sent as $key=>&$value){
```

Otherwise you are operating on a local copy that only keeps its value in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
function reg_sent($i){ 
    $reg_sent = "/[^A-Za-z0-9.,\n\r ]/"; 
    return preg_replace($reg_sent, '', $i); 
} 

foreach($reg_sent as $key => &$value){ 
    $value = reg_sent($value); 
}
unset($value);

var_dump($reg_sent);
```